# set selected in ng-options using unique filter

Tags: angularjs

How do i set the selected value of the ng-repeat when using unique filter ?

```
<div ng-controller="myAppList">
    <select ng-model="query" ng-options="c.cat as c.cat for c in products | unique:'cat'">
        <option value="0">Default</option>
    </select>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="c in products | filter:{cat:query}">
            {{c.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the app:

```
myApp.controller('myAppList', function myAppList($scope) {
  $scope.products = [
    {'name': 'Product 1', 'cat':'Cat 1',id:1},
    {'name': 'Product 2', 'cat':'Cat 2',id:2},
    {'name': 'Product 3', 'cat':'Cat 2',id:3},
    {'name': 'Product 4', 'cat':'Cat 3',id:4},
    {'name': 'Product 5', 'cat':'Cat 3',id:5},
    {'name': 'Product 6', 'cat':'Cat 2',id:6},
  ];

let index = $scope.products.map(function (x) { return x.id; }).indexOf(5);
console.warn(index);
    $scope.query=$scope.products[index];
});
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/068pm0uh/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it right.

```
$scope.query=$scope.products[index].cat;
                                    ^^^
```

With the `unique` filter, you're specifying `cat` as the property to filter on, so the `$scope.query` value you must set should be a corresponding `cat` value.

https://jsfiddle.net/j2uwqgz3/